# Failed to serialize object GridSecurityContext on local node

Tags: gridgain

While launching a local GridGain instance in a local node for the sake of testing I'm getting the following

```
class org.gridgain.grid.GridException: Failed to start SPI: GridTcpDiscoverySpi [locPort=47500, locPortRange=100, statsPrintFreq=0, netTimeout=5000, sockTimeout=2000, ackTimeout=5000, maxAckTimeout=600000, joinTimeout=0, hbFreq=2000, maxMissedHbs=1, threadPri=10, storesCleanFreq=60000, reconCnt=10, topHistSize=1000, gridName=null, locNodeId=dd235392-85b2-4f13-8a36-c433c5053c84, marsh=GridJdkMarshaller [], gridMarsh=org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedMarshaller@56589a42, locNode=GridTcpDiscoveryNode [id=dd235392-85b2-4f13-8a36-c433c5053c84, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=0, loc=true, ver=GridProductVersion [major=6, minor=1, maintenance=6, revTs=1401961981]], locAddr=null, locHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, ipFinder=GridTcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder [addrs=[/127.0.0.1:0], super=GridTcpDiscoveryIpFinderAdapter [shared=false]], metricsStore=null, spiState=CONNECTING, ipFinderHasLocAddr=true, recon=false, joinRes=GridTuple [val=null], nodeAuth=org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$3@6bdf5fb8, gridStartTime=0]
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:221)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:371)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridKernal.startManager(GridKernal.java:1523)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: class org.gridgain.grid.spi.GridSpiException: Failed to authenticate local node (will shutdown local node).
        at org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.GridTcpDiscoverySpi.joinTopology(GridTcpDiscoverySpi.java:1507)
        at org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.GridTcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart0(GridTcpDiscoverySpi.java:994)
        at org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.GridTcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(GridTcpDiscoverySpi.java:916)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:218)
        ... 10 more
```

You can find the full stack trace at this link http://pastebin.com/7D17vuCY

I've tried also to configure a local IP Finder like this, but with no joy.

```
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.GridTcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.GridTcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                    <property name="addresses" value="127.0.0.1"></property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

Any clue what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've solved this by setting the localAddress property

```
   <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.GridTcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="localAddress" value="127.0.0.1"/>
        </bean>
   </property>
```

Comment: Looks like you may have been joining another grid node with security permissions enabled.

Comment: Actually it happens also if I try to launch a GG daemon if I'm offline (unplugged ethernet and wi-fi switched off). I think because it is unable to find right local address.

Comment: The workaround is to run with -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true or upgrade to GridGain 6.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to run with -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true or upgrade to GridGain 6.2.0.